# How to redirect fslexyacc output to a specific folder in .fsproj?

Tags: .net-core, f#

I have the following `.fsproj` setup:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>

    <FsLexToolExe>fslex.dll</FsLexToolExe>
    <FsYaccToolExe>fsyacc.dll</FsYaccToolExe>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AST.fs" />

    <FsYacc Include="Parser.fsp">
      <OtherFlags>--module Parser</OtherFlags>
    </FsYacc>

    <FsLex Include="Lexer.fsl">
      <OtherFlags>--module Lexer --unicode</OtherFlags>
    </FsLex>

    <Compile Include="Parser.fsi" />
    <Compile Include="Parser.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Lexer.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FsLexYacc" Version="10.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I would like to have a directory that contains a parser module such that it contains all parser related files. I have tried to add a folder path to the auto-generated files as can seen in the below snippet, but that does not work.

```xml
  ...
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Parser/AST.fs" />

    <FsYacc Include="Parser/Parser.fsp">
      <OtherFlags>--module Parser</OtherFlags>
    </FsYacc>

    <FsLex Include="Parser/Lexer.fsl">
      <OtherFlags>--module Lexer --unicode</OtherFlags>
    </FsLex>

    <Compile Include="Parser/Parser.fsi" />
    <Compile Include="Parser/Parser.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Parser/Lexer.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FsLexYacc" Version="10.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Is there a way to acheive what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Winston!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [look at](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsLexYacc/blob/master/src/FsLexYacc.Build.Tasks/FsLexYacc.targets) `FsLexYacc.targets`, you'll find that it uses a property named `FsLexOutputFolder` to decide the output path.

```
<Target
        Name="CallFsLex"
        Inputs="@(FsLex)"

        Outputs="@(FsLex->'$(FsLexOutputFolder)%(Filename).fs')" <-- Outpath

        Condition="'@(FsLex)'!=''"
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
...
```

Similarly, there's `FsYaccOutputFolder` for FsYacc.

Correspondingly, we declare this property in our project file to set the target path. Here we're pushing all generated files to `<Project>/Parser`.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FsYaccOutputFolder>$(IntermediateOutputPath)Parser/</FsYaccOutputFolder>
    <FsLexOutputFolder>$(IntermediateOutputPath)Parser/</FsLexOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

---

If you're using it from the CLI, there's a `-o` option for the output path.